# How to make Single Selectable custom button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new in Flutter Development, I am practicing on an app of Airline Booking where user have to select a cabin of Airplane through tapping a button. So, I don't know the type of mentioned buttons and background functions, could anyone like to help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyToogleButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyToogleButtons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyToogleButtons> createState() => _MyToogleButtonsState();
}

class _MyToogleButtonsState extends State<MyToogleButtons> {
  List<bool> isSelected = [true, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ToggleButtons(
      fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      isSelected: isSelected,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 6),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              )),
          child: Text(
            "Economy",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 32.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Economy",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Economy",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Faheem, could you narrow this down to a specific question that we can address? Also, could you edit this to fix your code formatting?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onPressed` method on `ToggleButtons` and use like

```dart
isSelected: isSelected,
onPressed: (index) {
  for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
    isSelected[i] = i == index;
  }
  setState(() {});
},
```

Full widget

```dart
class MyToogleButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyToogleButtons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyToogleButtons> createState() => _MyToogleButtonsState();
}

class _MyToogleButtonsState extends State<MyToogleButtons> {
  List<bool> isSelected = [true, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ToggleButtons(
      fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      isSelected: isSelected,
      onPressed: (index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
          isSelected[i] = i == index;
        }
        setState(() {});
      },
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 6),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              )),
          child: Text(
            "Economy",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 32.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Economy",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Economy",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```